# On the etymology of Lacedaemon

Tags: ancient-greek, reference-request, etymology

King [Lacedaemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacedaemon_(mythology)) was the son of Zeus and of nymph [Taygete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taygete). He married [Sparta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparta_(mythology)), daughter of King [Eurotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurotas) of Laconia.

I would like to know more about the etymology of *Lacedaemon*.  The *daemon* part is easy.  However, where does *lace* come from?  Does it come from [lake](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%20%CE%9B%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B5%20%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%AF%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%82%20%20&op=translate)?

Being a neophyte, I do not even know where to look for such information. Advice would be most welcome.

---

<sub>**Related:** [Is there a tale of Zeus having sex with a deer?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/3063/2654)</sub>

Comment: This really belongs more on linguistics.SE than here. Note also that ancient Greek is thought to have adopted many thousands of place names and proper names from an unknown pre-historic language that predated the coming of proto-Greek speakers.

Comment: Do you want it moved to Linguistics?

Comment: @Semaphore If anything, it should go to Latin, which also covers ancient Greek. Send it over there and we'd be happy to adopt it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, we just don't know. There is no clear Greek etymology for it, not just the initial Lake- part, but the whole word. This is from Beekes' etymological dictionary:

> Λακεδαίμων, -ονος [f.] town and country on the river Eurotas (ll.). <PG?>
> .DIAL Myc. *ra-ke-da-mi-ni-jo* /Lakedaimnios/ and *[ra-]ke-da-mo-ni-jo* /Lakedaimonios/, cf. Lejeune *RPh*. 68 (1994): 165-168.
>
> ...
>
> ETYM The meaning of the appellative is unknown, **so the name remains without etymology**. Several proposals: a) to λακεδάμα [/lakedama/]...'bitter water [poured over groats] which the [Macedonian] countrymen drink' (H.); b) the second member is δαίμων /daimon/ in the sense 'part' (BechteI 1921, 2: 370); c) dissimilated from *Λακεν-αίμων /Laken-aimon/, to > Λάκων /Lakon/ and another ethnonym Αἵμων /Aimon/ (Szemerenyi *Glotta* 38 (1960): 14ff. with
> ample discussion).
>
> Acc. to Fick 1905: 90, however, it is rather a Hellenisation of a Pre-Greek word. Frisk thinks that Λάκων is a shortened form of Λακε-δαιμόνιος /Lake-daemonios/; the element Λακε- /Lake/ is found in Λάκε-θεν /Lake-then/, a deme of Eretria.

- <sub>The transcriptions of Greek words are my own and follows the same type as Beekes' does for Mycenaean words. The "PG" in the beginning means "pre-Greek."</sub>

Under Λάκων, Beekes has some further information:

> ETYM Acc. to Dittenberger Herm. 41 (1906): 196, hypocoristic for official Λακεδαιμόνιος, which is why the fem. Λακαίνα /lakaina/ (for Λακεδαιμόνια /Lakedaimonia/ is found almost everywhere. Krahe IF 57 (1940): 119 supposes the name to be Illyrian and connects *Lacinium*, a promontory in southern Italy, *Iuno Lacinia*.
>
> Fur.: 171<sup>117</sup> thinks that the suffix -αινα is Pre-Greek.

So as you can see, there are many guesses, but no one knows for sure. It's doubtful that -daimon itself is even related to the Greek word *daimon*, and if so in what sense it is being used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for proposing the migration.  It was a mistake to assume that the *daemon* in *Lacedaemon* is the same as in *Eudaemonia*.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's an easy association to make! I myself assumed so up until the time I looked it up. I'm still not sure why it can't be, but maybe someone will chime in with that.

Comment: @cmw I don't think there's any specific reason it *can't* be δαίμων -- it's just unclear (as you say).